# Whether the function $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^2(1-x^2)^{n-1}$ is continuous?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, continuity, power-series

So the given function is 
$$f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$$ defined as 
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^2(1-x^2)^{n-1}$$.

To determine $f$ is continuous or not?

So what I did, I took $y=1-x^2$ to simplify it and replace the summation.

So I arrived at $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-y)y^{n-1}$$
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}y^{n-1}-y^n$$

By taking the partial sum, 
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{k}y^{n-1}-y^n=1-y^k$$
Taking limit as $k\to \infty$ I got $f(x)=1$. So the function is continuous. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: Note that $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: If the value of $f$ is different at the end points does it effect the continuity?

Comment: So... your question is whether a function $f$ defined by $f(x)=1$ for every $x\ne0$ and $f(0)=0$, is continuous or not?

Comment: Yes. I mean from the given definition I arrived at the limit $f(x)=1$, for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$. Now firstly is my method of arriving at the limit is correct or not? Secondly from these information what can I say about the continuity of $f$? @Did

Comment: If the question is the one in my first comment then [Houston, we have a problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lTSVOnhLtCs)... What is continuity, already?

Comment: Ya I got it, my mind went black. It is not continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is correct as far as it goes, but there two points missing: The ends of the interval.

With $x=0,y=1$, the final step is different and sum converges towards $1-1=0$.

Therefore $f$ is not continuous at this point.

Comment: I didn't understand your 3rd line. "the original sum contains" part. Can you explain it please.

Comment: I was wrong. Edited.